# biopython PDB: how to reference atom list by an atom's serial number

Tags: python, biopython

i'm quite struggling with biopython. i am successful in getting a list of all atoms from a structure object as well as getting/setting coordinates and retrieving a serial number:

```
from Bio import PDB

pdb = "file.pdb"
name = "file"
p = PDB.PDBParser()
struct_in = p.get_structure(name, pdb)

for atom in PDB.Selection.unfold_entities(struct_in, target_level='A'):
    atom.set_coord(np.array((1,2,3)))
    atom.transform(unity3,(2,-2,1))
    print atom.get_serial_number()
```

however, i am not able to reference a certain atom (index 23) by its serial number in order to change its coordinates. i am looking for something similar to the fictive "get_atom_by_index()" function in the second line of the following (which doesn't work like that):

```
atomList = PDB.Selection.unfold_entities(struct_in, target_level='A')
atomList.get_atom_by_index(23).set_coord(newCoord)
```

of course, i could do something like

```
for i in atomList:
    if atomList[i].get_serial_number() == 23:
        atomList[i].set_coord(newCoord)
```

but i would prefer avoiding this additional loop. there MUST be a more convenient way of doing it!

thanks in advance
fred

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific index number, then why don't you simply do this:

```
atomList[23].set_coord(newCoord)
```

Comment: because the list index (going from [0:len(atomList)-1]) doesn't equal the serial number as given in the pdb file which sometimes are not consecutive.

Comment: It should not be incosistent. It should be either from 0 to ... or from 1 ...; doesn't make sense!

Comment: imagine, you have atom numbers [4,5,6,23,24,25,...] in a pdb file which are not consecutive. and indeed, this is not unusual. have you ever seen the content of a pdb file? anyway, these atoms would be indexed with [0,1,2,3,4,5,...] in the list variable.

Comment: Okay, got it! Will be back to you soon!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the PDB in a dict creating the keys from the atoms serial numbers:

```
selection = PDB.Selection.unfold_entities(struct_in, target_level='A')
serial_numbers = [atom.serial_number for atom in selection]

selection_dict = dict(zip(serial_numbers, selection))

# selection_dict is now something like:
# {1: <Atom N>, 2: <Atom CA>, 3: <Atom C>, ...}
```

Now you can access the dict with the keys, without looping:

```
selection_dict[23].set_coord(np.array((1,2,3)))
```